# XmlSearch() does not process an individual XML node in an array

Tags: xml, xpath, coldfusion

I have an XML document that I've assigned to a ColdFusion variable. Calling `XmlSearch()` on this document produces an array of XML nodes. Calling `XmlSearch()` on one of those XML nodes produces the same output as if calling it on the original XML document.

What could the issue be?

Here's a code example (CFScript):

```
// xmlSource is an XML file that has been read in
xmlDoc = XmlParse(xmlSource);

// "return" is a high-level XML node in xmlSource that appears more than one time
xmlNodeArray = XmlSearch(xmlDoc, "//return");

// a single "return" node from xmlDoc
xmlNode = xmlNodeArray[1];

// "recipients" is an XML node that appears one or more times beneath each "return" XML node
xmlArray = XmlSearch(xmlNode, "//recipients");

// this prints out all of the "recipients" nodes in xmlDoc instead of just from xmlNode
WriteDump(xmlArray);
```

Comment: Try to use "./recipients" as your XPath.

Comment: This might cast some light on the scene for you: http://blog.adamcameron.me/2014/01/expectations-management-what-does.html

Comment: @abbottmw `./recipients` worked, thank you. ColdFusion appears to have more or less an array of pointer-style variables in the return value of `XmlSearch()`... making the entire original `xmlDoc` available from `xmlNode`.

Comment: @AdamCameron Thanks for the nice explanation in your blog post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the XPath. Changing

```
xmlArray = XmlSearch(xmlNode, "//recipients");
```

to

```
xmlArray = XmlSearch(xmlNode, "./recipients");
```

fixed it.

Comment: To clarify for those who did not read [Adam's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35066144/xmlsearch-does-not-process-an-individual-xml-node-in-an-array#comment57857324_35066144), using the relative `.`, rather than `//`, forces xmlSearch to search starting with the provided node, ie `xmlNode`, rather than the entire document.